# rpy2 code snippet returns an empty object

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using rpy2 to use a R library in Python. The library has a function prebas() that returns an array in which the item with index [8] is the output. When I write this output to CSV within the R code snippet, everything works as expected (the output is a CSV over 200kB). However, when I return the same object (PREBASout[8]), it returns an empty object. So, obviously, when I write that object to CSV, the file is empty.

```
run_prebasso = robjects.r('''
        weather <- read.csv("/home/example_inputs/weather.csv",header = T)
        PAR = c(weather$PAR,weather$PAR,weather$PAR)
        TAir = c(weather$TAir,weather$TAir,weather$TAir)
        Precip = c(weather$Precip,weather$Precip,weather$Precip)
        VPD = c(weather$VPD,weather$VPD,weather$VPD)
        CO2 = c(weather$CO2,weather$CO2,weather$CO2)
        DOY = c(weather$DOY,weather$DOY,weather$DOY)
        library(Rprebasso)

        PREBASout = prebas(nYears = 100, PAR=PAR,TAir=TAir,VPD=VPD,Precip=Precip,CO2=CO2)
        write.csv(PREBASout[8],"/home/outputs/written_in_r.csv",row.names = F)

        PREBASout[8]

''')

r_write_csv = robjects.r['write.csv']

r_write_csv(run_prebasso, "/home/outputs/written_in_py.csv")
```

This is what the code snippet returns:

```
(Pdb) run_prebasso
<rpy2.rinterface.NULLType object at 0x7fc1b31e6b48> [RTYPES.NILSXP]
```

**Question**: Why aren't `written_in_py.csv` and `written_in_r.csv` the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the bug. The problem was in the line

```
write.csv(PREBASout[8],"/home/outputs/written_in_r.csv",row.names = F)
```

This statement was returned instead of what I wanted (PREBASout[8]). When I removed it or assigned it to a variable, everything worked as expected.